# Transport keyboard/mouse events to a keyboard/mouse-less remote host

Tags: networking, multimedia, remote-control

I want to send keyboard and mouse events from a small ARMv7 computer board to a remote one, which has no keyboard nor mouse. I'm planning to send these events on a locally implemented CAN bus. The controlling board has a touch screen that is detected as a touchpad. Support for a hardware keyboard is planned but typically there's none but a virtual keyboard.

---

**The context:** both boards shall be combined as a master/slave ensemble in a multimedia installation. The one that runs the multimedia platform (typically but not limited to [Kodi](http://kodi.tv/)) is the slave and has no keyboard, no mouse; it should receive its input events from the CAN bus. The master, controlling board is also connected to a small display, which plays the role of a keyboard and touchpad when the slave multimedia board is turned on. The cross-development toolchain is **Gentoo Linux**.

---

So I was wondering about the most straightforward way to send local keyboard and mouse (touchpad) events to the remote host, given that I'm no *kernel* developer.

For instance I could figure out using `netcat` to send local keyboard/mouse events (from `/dev/input/*`) to a remote machine but as far as I understand there must be a keyboard and mouse plugged on the remote machine... unless there is some kind of dummy driver available that I could use on the remote end. (This said, I tried but it didn't work.)

I'm not against kernel input module development, for instance, but I'd rather combine user space applications if possible or develop one if necessary. I would also prefer sending "raw" hardware events rather than assume there's a graphical engine such as Xorg or Wayland running on the remote board. Unless discouraged of course.

So in the end I'm wondering if I should either

- hack `lirc` and add CAN support, for instance or
- hack linux input drivers.

If there's a more hassle-free way, I'm all open.

Comment: Do/can you have an X server on both boards? If so [x2x](https://github.com/dottedmag/x2x) might be a solution.

Comment: It is indeed planned. However I prefer not to rely on the presence of X as I'd like the solution to be agnostic of the graphical environment. Further investigating lead me to [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput), which looks exactly like what I'm looking for. I can manage to find a way to send input events to a remote host and `uinput` allows for injecting them directly into the event queue on the remote host.

Answer (score 0):

I just did this yesterday with [Input Interception tools framework (gitlab.com/interception)](https://gitlab.com/interception/linux/tools).

Install is easy:

- Install the handful of prerequisite packages mentioned there (+ `pkgconf`)
- Clone the repo
- run `cmake` with the options given in the README.

Quick POC:

On source computer (the one with the keyboard):
`src/interception-tools/build/intercept -g /dev/input/by-id/usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-if02-event-mouse  | nc des.ti.nat.ion 9876`

On destination machine (the one you want to "beam" events to):
`nc -l -p 9876 | src/interception-tools/build/uinput`

If destination machine has no other Input sources, you may need to export the keyboard-specific `yaml`:

> uinput -p -d /dev/input/by-id/my-kbd
> prints my-kbd characteristics in YAML, which itself can be fed back to
> uinput as uinput -c my-kbd.yaml

This was on Debian bullseye between ARM64@5.13 and AMD64@5.10.

If this works for you, you still have to integrate that into your system startup files, and then it will be automatic and seamless.